# How can I retrieve the highest point from a list of points?

Tags: c#

I want extract the high amplitude portion from the audio and related time.  Please help me with how I can return the value of x,y axis then sort the value of to get highest point.

```
NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32 wave = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(open.FileName));
byte[] Buffer = new byte[163840];
int read = 0;

while (wave.Position < wave.Length)
{
    read = wave.Read(Buffer, 0, 16384);   
}

for (int i = 0; i < read / 4; i++)
{                
    chart1.Series["wave"].Points.Add(BitConverter.ToSingle(Buffer, i * 4));  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following expression to return the max in your list.

```
chart1.Series["wave"].Points.ToList().Max()
```